# Interactive generation of documents using predefined strings

Tags: windows, productivity, plain-text, desktop-client, forms

I'm looking for a tool to help expedite the writing of reports that often have the same exact sentences/paragraphs. The idea is to generate documents based on a collection of predefined strings, in an interactive manner.

The tool should allow the user to define several "text sections", and for each section the user will be able to provide a list of strings. Then, when a new document is requested, for each section, the user will be presented with a list of checkboxes (one for each string; possibly including a "fuzzy" search field) and after confirming the choices, text sections are created.

#### Requirements:

1. (Must) Support for multiple "text sections", each having its own collection of strings.
2. (Must) Updating the lists of strings should be *objectively simple* for a non-tech-savvy user.
3. (Must) The output should be plain text, so that it can be easily copied and edited.
4. (N2H) The list of strings should be searchable. That is, when typing some text, the list of strings should be filtered on the fly to entries that contain this text.

#### Other notes:

- Gratis solutions are preferred but not a must. If the tool requires payment, it should have a demo/trial version available.
- The tool/software doesn't have to be standalone (i.e. I don't mind if it requires Python, Java, MS Office, MATLAB, ...).
- I know about [MS Word's AutoText feature](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/automatically-insert-text-0bc40cab-f49c-4e06-bcb2-cd43c1674d1b) but it is very inconvenient for this purpose since it's not meant for this volume of text - it doesn't allow searching, texts cannot be added in bulk, organizing texts into sections is difficult, etc.
- My fallback is to code this myself or create some Excel-based tool, but this is really the last resort due to the amount of time it could take.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to write Python plugin for [CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/) editor. Plugin can show dialogs and add/change text or files. You can ask this work (for $) at CudaText forum, I think.